# Angular Devise non encrypted password

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

I'm learning how to use [angular_devise](https://github.com/cloudspace/angular_devise)

I'm registering new user like this:

```
    vm.onSubmit = function() {
        Auth.register({ email: "hello@gmail.com", password: "sdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdfs" });
    };
```

and this is my **Request Payload**

```
{user: {email: "hello@gmail.com", password: "sdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdfs"}}
```

as you can see the password in the request payload is not encrypted.

I read the angular_devise documentation, but I couldn't find how to setup angular_devise so it would send encrypted password.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I haven't used angular_devise. However, it's normal that your password reaches the server unencrypted. It gets encrypted by devise when it's stored in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be legitimate behavior. However, if you really want to encrypt the connection data, there's two ways to do it:

- Simple Way

SSL over HTTP. Just buy a certificate and using a secure connection (https)

- RSA Way

In case you want to make secured connection over plain HTTP, I would recommend to use the RSA encryption in both ends of your application.
[here is an example of library for doing that on javascript side](https://github.com/maxogden/ezcrypto-js). On the ruby side, the standard library should have already the methods to make it.

This way is used by some services like Stripe or Braintree to transfert securely the credit card number to their services for example.